# Need Advice on what to invest in?

Tags: investing, savings

If I have some money saved up, in our current economy what would be the best way to invest lets say... $1000-$3000 dollars? Or would it be best to just save this money? Any and all advice is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Specific investment advice is off-topic, but would highly recommend reading the marked duplicate to see if there are other options (paying off debt, saving an emergency fund, etc.) that may be more applicable.

Comment: I would go with a short-term TIP mutual fund or ETF instead of a savings account. The short-term TIP does take the interest-rate risk of a 2-year government bond but also pays the rate of inflation. Or for leveraged and hedged income invest in most any closed-end-fund. But it might not be a good time for stocks, or for high-yield bonds, or for mortgages. So consider a closed-end-fund of TIP's and that's WIW or WIA.

Comment: @SSpring thank you for a real response instead of just being snide and unhelpful like others here. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask anonymous strangers on the internet for suggestions about what  to invest in then you probably shouldn't be investing.

A better plan would be to invest in a free library card and begin the road to financial literacy.  If you'd rather not travel, try the internet.  Web sites like Investopedia will provide a rather broad based knowledge of the financial markets.  Good luck.